# Automate file upload using jQuery Fileuploader with webdriver

Tags: jquery

Has anyone tried to automate file upload using jQuery Fileuploader with webdriver before?  I am using selenium 2.0a6 and pythonbinding.

The webapp under the test, https://contactsui.ovi.com is using jQuery Fileuploader to upload one phone at a time.  Click on one link Add photo will pop up a File Upload Window.  Once the file is chosen, it will automatically attach the file to qqfile.  The challenge I am facing is that it seems jQuery Fileuploader does not generate a  pair.  Detecting or finding the element fail.  I heard that I can use Webdriver's execute_script to call jQuery directly to attach the file but how do I do that?

If you have done something similar to automate file upload using jQuery Fileuploader with webdriver, please share your successful experience.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test file upload with Jasmine BDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673001/how-to-test-file-upload-with-jasmine-bdd)